# How do I configure apache, so that my client certificate authentication works for two specific URLs only?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, authentication

I'm following **[this guide](https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/apache-ssl-client-auth)** in order to establish client-based, certificate authentication on my website.

The goal: Allow 2 users access to 2 specific URLs: `/login` and `/admin`. When any of the 2 users access the mentioned locations, they need to provide a certificate that identifies them (imported via a .pfx file).

I completed seven steps of the **[guide](https://community.hetzner.com/tutorials/apache-ssl-client-auth)**. The 8th step deals with adjusting the apache config. The issue is that the guide adjusts the config cross-host, while I only need the certificate authentication to be active when one of the two URLs (above) is accessed.

How do I configure this?

Comment: Step 6 wasn't very clear.  You can place the `SSLVerifyClient` in .htaccess files in the /login and /admin directories, or in '<Directory . . .>' sections for granular control.  If you're concerned about step 8, that directive can be put in your virtual host config to only affect a single host.